Trace, $W^{m,p}_0(\Omega)$ and hypothesis on the boundary of $\Omega$
In the book A First Course in Sobolev Spaces: Second Edition from Giovanni Leoni is proved:
$\textbf{Theorem 18.7} $Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, with $N \geq 2$, be an open set whose boundary $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz continuous. Let $1 \leq p < \infty$, and let $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Then $\operatorname{Tr}(u) = 0$ if and only if $u \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$.
To extend Theorem 18.7, the author assumes that $\partial \Omega$ is of class $C^{m-1,1}$ and proves the following:
$\textbf{Theorem 18.8}$ Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$, with $m \geq 2$, and let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, where $N \geq 2$, be an open set whose boundary $\partial \Omega$ is of class $C^{m-1,1}$. Let $1 \leq p < \infty$, and let $u \in W^{m,p}(\Omega)$. Then:
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(u) = 0, \quad \operatorname{Tr}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}\right) = 0, \quad \ldots, \quad \operatorname{Tr}\left(\frac{\partial^{m-1} u}{\partial \nu^{m-1}}\right) = 0
$$
if and only if $u \in W^{m,p}_0(\Omega)$.
The question arises: is there a version of Theorem 18.7 with the same hypothesis on the boundary of $\Omega$ as in Theorem 18.7, i.e., where $\partial \Omega$ is Lipschitz continuous? In the case $m=2$ would this be true?

"The question arises: is there a version of Theorem 18.7..." I assume you mean 18.8 ?
